# Finding latest release links on website for C++ Application

Tags: php, c++

Basically I have written a game plugin that will allow server admins to update their administration tools from within game rather than having to go download it and install it. The releases are updated regularly, and the beta versions are nightly builds.

I am trying to find a way to grab the links from the website, but I cannot think of anyway to do this off of the top of my head. Was hoping someone here might be able to suggest something that would work.

http://www.sourcemod.net/snapshots.php

Thats the website, basically I am trying to grab the links for the latest stable branch, and latest development branch.

Comment: I have requested a file manifest be made available but as of right now that isn't an option so I am looking for other possible ideas.

Comment: You want to scrape a webpage and extract links to use in a c++ app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple and can be broken down into a few steps:

1. Fetching the links & files: Use cURL/cURLpp or Poco C++. They are easy but you may spend a few hours to learn :)
2. Processing/Extracting the links: Use TidyHTML to make sure the HTML is converted to valid XHTML and use XPath to extract the links. Can use libxml2 & libxslt. I'd prefer Qt C++
3. Fetch the extracted links and save them to pre-defined paths. Boost Filesystem may ease your task with file system.

Note that if I were to do this (well, I've done this before), I'd use only Qt C++ as it provides everything I need. Btw, Qt C++ has a dead simple way to send GET/POST requests & fetch files :) Good luck!

### EDIT:

Qt C++ XML also provides CSS-like selectors which avoids you using any other libraries: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt4-6-intro.html#dom-access-api

In short: Just go for Nokia Qt C++ in all the steps. Download from: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it Qt would have been a good choice, but the rest of it is already done and I have LibCurl implemented already (for the file download) so I will just use that. Thank you for the help. I know very little about parsing HTML but guess it is time to learn more.

Comment: Yup :) HTML parsing is rather important if you need to extract links, images and styles or want to traverse through the web. If you want to avoid Qt C++, remember to use TidyHTML to convert to valid XHTML before using with any Expat/libxml2/Xerces/libxslt libraries :)

Answer (score 0):

you could ask them if they have some sort of web service to call?

i.e. you could request the latest version which would return a revision number, you compare that against your current version, if an update is required you call another web service to request the location of the files to download.